# c# winforms Form Load ComboBox DropDownList get value from XML file

Tags: c#, winforms

XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<XMLFILE>
 <Active>0</Active>
 <Hits_Method>1</Hits_Method>
</XMLFILE>
```

What i'm trying to do is on Form1_Load get the value of ComboBox4 from XML File (Hits_Method) and when the program start to show me the value. i try something like this but didn't work out

```
// ------------------- StartUP Load
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // --------------- Read XML File / Data: Settings_Ads_General
    String xmlfile = "Settings_General.xml";
    XmlTextReader xreader = new XmlTextReader(xmlfile);

    string comboBox4Value = xreader.GetAttribute("Hits_Method");
    comboBox4.SelectedIndex = comboBox4Value;

}
```

Comment: Dude, your getting an Attribute when you want an Element

Comment: i try something like this:

            string comboBox4Value = xreader.ReadElementString("Hits_Method");
            comboBox4.SelectedIndex = comboBox4Value;

but i get error "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'int'"

Comment: Check my answer for the convert type problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // --------------- Read XML File / Data: Settings_Ads_General
        String xmlfile = "Settings_General.xml";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(xmlfile);

        string comboBox4Value = doc.SelectSingleNode("XMLFILE/Hits_Method").InnerText;
        comboBox4.SelectedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(comboBox4Value);

    }
```

The `SelectSingleNode` method extracts data based on an XPath expression. And "XMLFILE/Hits_Method" is the XPath that leads to your value.

Comment: No problems. But after I have been looking through your previous questions you should consider looking at tutorials first. Any decent book will answer the next 150 questions you will have. I don't want to be mean. We all started at some point. But I guess a somewhat structured learning process would be best.

Comment: i start with c# winforms 3 days ago ... i come from php programing but some commands is not desame, the best way to learn something is to do something ... reading is not helping much if you dont try to make something

Answer (score 1):

I will use XmlDocument and XmlNode classes.

```
{
    String sPath = "file.xml"
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(sPath)
    XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("XMLFILE/Hits_Method");
    if (node != null)
        comboBox4.SelectedIndex = node.InnerText;
}
```